# PHP Can't access object protected attribute value

Tags: php, object, protected

I have a object property that looks like this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($object);
```

the result:

```
ValueObjects\Number\Integer Object
(
    [value:protected] => 50
)
```

i tried to access it like this:

```
echo $object->getValue();
echo $object->value;
echo $object->value();
```

but all of them gives me an error

Comment: Because `getValue()` doesn't exist, `value` is an inaccessible property from outside of object context, and `value()` is a method that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sherif so how can i get the `50` value?

Comment: Protected properties and methods cannot be accessed publicly like that. They're only available inside the class' methods. Now, if I had to guess (*and this is a total guess*) an Object named `Number\Integer` probably implements some kind of `__toString` magic.

Comment: who wrote the class? there must be some method to use to extract that value somewhere, use the manual if there are any or dive right into the source code